# Как привязать static ObservableCollection к GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Не обновляется UI при изменении коллекции.

Код класса

```
public static class Contractors
{
    static ObservableCollection<Contractor> ContractorsList;
    public static ObservableCollection<Contractor> CONTRACTORS
    {
        get { return ContractorsList; }
    }
}
```

Код xaml

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
 x:Name="contractorsTable" 
 Grid.Row="1" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 FontSize="12px"
 IsReadOnly="True"
 ShowSearchPanel="True"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        MouseDoubleClick="ContractorsTable_OnMouseDoubleClick"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static zaDelo:Contractors.CONTRACTORS}}"
        >
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IdContractors}" Header="Код" Width="45" ShowDistinctFilters="False" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Iname}" Header="Наименование" Width="2*" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding BidPrice}" Header="Цена" Width="45" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Телефон" IsFilterable="False" Width="*" IsSortable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email" IsFilterable="False" IsSortable="False" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Header="ОТВ" Width="50" TextAlignment="Center" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding City}" Header="Город" Width="60" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Region}" Header="Район" Width="60" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Loyalty}" Header="Лояльность" Width="60" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="" CellStyleSelector="{StaticResource ClientBonusS}" Width="15"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IdCart}" Header="Карта" Width="45" TextAlignment="Center" IsFilterable="False"/>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ContractorGroup}" Header="Назначение" Width="*" IsFilterable="False"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как связать что бы обновления в UI было вместе с изменениями в коллекции.

Comment: Вы изменяете коллекцию или объект в коллекции?

Comment: да обновление самой статической коллекции происходит либо при вызове метода либо по таймеру в потоках, потому как с базой могут работать несколько человек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` оповещает об изменении самой коллекции (добавление, удаление и т.п.). Если вы хотите видеть изменение элемента в коллекции, тогда сам элемент должен реализовывать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. То есть:

```
public class Contractor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение!